# Using real analysis

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Prove that $$ 
\lim \limits_{n\to \infty }\left( 2+\frac{1}{n+1} \right) =2 $$

Comment: Please show your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Write down your definition of a limit.  How can you get the expression above to fit that definition?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are asking for some type of $(\epsilon, \delta)$ argument. The first fact before beginning is to recall that if $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are convergent sequences, say with limits $A,B$ respectively, then $\lim_{n} (a_n)+(b_n) = \lim_n a_n + \lim_n b_n$. In your case, take $a_n = 2$ and so let's analyze $b_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Here $\frac{1}{n+1}< \frac{1}{n}$ and so if you can show $\frac{1}{n}$ has a limit, then $\frac{1}{n+1}$ will have the same limit since it is a subsequence. If $\frac{1}{n}< \epsilon$ then $n> \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Therefore, given $\epsilon >0$, if you let $N_0> \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ where $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ then;

$$\frac{1}{n+1}< \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon; \forall n \geq N_0$$

Hence, using the fact that $a_n + b_n \to A+B $ then $2+\frac{1}{n+1} \to 2$ and $n \to \infty$ since the above argument implies $\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$.

$\textbf{Question}$: Use the method above to determine the limits of $b_n = 3 + \frac{2}{n+2}$ and $n \to \infty$.